# Custom the AccessTokenExpires of OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, access-token, owin

I want to custom my login scenario in my MVC 5 project.
I followed the SPA template to use oauth bearer token for authentication. But I want to add some logic to control the AccessTokenExpires time.

From this [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) and A de Baugh's comment, I can change the expire time of the ticket properties. But I still can't find where to add my logic to my custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class.
Basically I want to add something like Remember Me by passing more parameter when sending the login request.
At the moment I must create another controller to handle login

The login method of the controller looks like

```
// POST api/Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);

            // my check for remember me
            if (model.RememberMe)
                properties.ExpiresUtc = properties.IssuedUtc + TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
            else properties.ExpiresUtc = properties.IssuedUtc + TimeSpan.FromHours(3);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);

            return Ok(new
            {
                user = model.UserName,
                access_token = accessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket),
                expire = properties.ExpiresUtc
            });
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Invalid username or password");
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Authentication

```
private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
{
    get { return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
}
```

And the accessTokenFormat to protect ticket is `Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat`

Am I doing this in an unusual way? I believe there is a better approach to archive this.
Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally understanding your questions but by rolling my one OAuthAuthenicationServerProvider I found a very good example from [@leastprivilege](http://www.twitter.com/leastprivilege) on github: The SimpleRefreshTokenProvider ... this describes (with comments) how to handle the refresh cycle of a token. Maybe this is a good starting point to abstract your own example.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/samples/OAuth2/EmbeddedResourceOwnerFlowWithRefreshTokens/EmbeddedAuthorizationServer/Provider/SimpleRefreshTokenProvider.cs

HTH

P.S.: It is also worth it to spend some time reading his blog about security OAuth, ... http://leastprivilege.com/